# How to read pdf file in Django

Tags: python, django, pdf, model

This is my view.. In the blank space after open I want to read a file but I dont to what to write to make it dynamic..

```
def home(request):
    image_data = open('', 'rb').read()
    return HttpResponse(image_data, mimetype='application/pdf')
```

This my model here file is uploaded .. Its is either pdf or .doc .. I want to read the file uploaded

```
from django.db import models


class CV(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='media')
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
def home(request):
  file = request.FILES['yourHtmlFileFieldName']
  image_date = open(file,'rb').read()
```